# Como enviar dados com JS? sem atualizar página

Tags: php, javascript, html, aplicação-web, game

Estou tentando criar um Jogo em HTML e preciso de um modo de enviar dados para um banco (MYSQL) e gostaria de saber como posso enviar dados do site para um servidor sem que a página atualize.

Caso alguem conheça algumas bibliotecas que eu possa usar para desenvolver um jogo 2D em html. Por favor se manifeste.

Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Voce pode fazer isso utilizando javascript, mas você tem algum código implementado ?

Comment: eu tenho um código, porém não sei fazer essa função com js puro. se souber alguma maneira, pf me ajude

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque seu código se possível ou parte dele, mas a dúvida é, voce esta usando submit no seu form?

Comment: eu ainda não tenho um código dessa funcão ... antes disso estava passando as variaveis JS para o PHP e enviando para o banco.

Comment: Faça isso que irei te indicar eu testei e deu certo aqui e me de um feedback, caso positivo marque a resposta como melhor para que outros usuários entendam que essa resposta irá sanar sua dúvida. Podendo assim, futuramente ajudar outros usuários

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para enviar dados sem que sua página atualize, faça refresh ou algo do tipo. É necessário utilizar  javascript com um serialize .

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ajax').submit(function(){
        var dados = $( this ).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "nomedoarquivo.php",
            data: dados,
            success: function( data )
            {
                alert( data );
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Mas para isso tera que alterar sua tag form, no caso se ela estiver assim

```
<form action="nomedoarquivo.php" method="POST">
```

Tera que deixar assim, como irei mostrar abaixo, afinal no JavaScript já estará indicando o nome do arquivo e o método de envio que será POST

```
<form action="" method="" id="ajax">
```

Lembrando que neste caso deverá ter um submit para que funcione o envio dos dados corretamente, irei dar um exemplo abaixo de um submit

```
 <input type="submit" value="Salvar informações">
```

Comment: Deu certo cara... obrigado, você acaba de salvar um jogo em desenvolvimento.

Comment: Vi que fez uma sugestão de trocar sucess por error, não faca isso. Se deu certo não tente reinventar alterando o código